# CRM JavaScript - SendAppNotification

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, crm

We're attempting to emulate the CRM Toast Notification JavaScript functionality described in this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/send-in-app-notifications?tabs=clientapi).

Using the following first example from the article, the notification is successfully sent to the user:

```
var SendAppNotificationRequest = new Example.SendAppNotificationRequest(
    title = "Welcome",
    recipient = "/systemusers(8d585985-e1f4-ed11-8818-0022483d019b)",
    body = "Welcome to the world of app notifications!",
    priority = 200000000,
    iconType = 100000000,
    toastType = 200000000,
);
```

However, when we attempt the second following example, that includes an overrideContent element, we receive an error:

```
var SendAppNotificationRequest = new Example.SendAppNotificationRequest(title = "SLA critical",
    recipient = "/systemusers(8d585985-e1f4-ed11-8818-0022483d019b)",
    body = "Record assigned to you is critically past SLA.",
    iconType = 100000003,
    toastType = 200000000,
    overrideContent = {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
        "title": "**SLA critical**",
        "body": "Case record [Complete overhaul required (sample)](?pagetype=entityrecord&etn=incident&id=0a9f62a8-90df-e311-9565-a45d36fc5fe8) assigned is critically past SLA and has been escalated to your manager."
    }
);
```

Here is the error we are receiving when attempting to execute that second example:

```
"message": "Error identified in Payload provided by the user for Entity :'', 
For more information on this error please follow this help link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2195293  
---->  InnerException : System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.
```

Has anyone seen this before or have any ideas why this second example is returning this error?

**Update:**

Looking at the JSON payload in the Network tab (thanks @Andrew Butenko), I saw the following...

```
{
"Title":"SLA critical",
"Recipient":"/systemusers(8d585985-e1f4-ed11-8818-0022483d019b)",
"Body":"Record assigned to you is critically past SLA.",
"Priority":100000003,
"IconType":200000000,
"ToastType":[object Object],
"Expiry":null,
"OverrideContent":null,
"Actions":null
}
```

It looks like the IconType, ToastType, OverrideContent elements are being assigned incorrectly.  Essentially, they've been shifted up 1 element leaving OverrideElement as NULL.

I changed the variable declaration/assignment to the following which works...

```
var SendAppNotificationRequest = new alya_shared.SendAppNotificationRequest();
sendAppNotificationRequest.Title = "SLA critical",
sendAppNotificationRequest.Recipient = "/systemusers(8d585985-e1f4-ed11-8818-0022483d019b)",
sendAppNotificationRequest.Body = "Record assigned to you is critically past SLA.",
sendAppNotificationRequest.IconType = 100000003;
sendAppNotificationRequest.ToastType = 200000000;
sendAppNotificationRequest.OverrideContent = {
"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
"title": "**SLA critical**",
"body": "Case record [Complete overhaul required (sample)](?pagetype=entityrecord&etn=incident&id=0a9f62a8-90df-e311-9565-a45d36fc5fe8) assigned is critically past SLA and has been escalated to your manager."
};
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking network traffic and checking if it gives more information. The following steps describe what you can do to see the network traffic:

Google Chrome:

- Open developer tools (Menu > More tools > Developer tools or Ctrl + Shift + I or F12)
- Select the Network tab.
- Perform the steps to cause the behavior/issue

Firefox (41+) :

- Go to Menu > Web Developer > Network
- Reload the page you want to get the log for
- Perform the steps to cause the behavior/issue

Internet Explorer and Edge:

- Open Developer Tools (F12)
- Go to the network tab and click on the green arrow to start the tool
- List item

Perform the steps to cause the behavior/issue